# NoReverseMatch at `redirect()` with existing view methods

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've burrowed through the mound of `NoReverseMatch` questions here on SO and elsewhere, but to no avail.

I have a view method, `clean`, and within in a `redirect`:

```
def clean(request, aid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(enrich,
            permanent=True,
            aid=account.id)
    else:
        return render(request, 'clean.html')
```

And a view method called `enrich`:

```
def enrich(request, aid):
    return HttpResponse('this be the enrich page')
```

It has a `path` in `urls.py`:

```
path('<aid>/enrich/', views.enrich, name='enrich'),
```

And yet, when calling on the `redirect` in the `clean` method, I am lovingly told this by Python:

```
NoReverseMatch at /app2/<aid>/clean/

Reverse for 'app2.views.enrich' not found. 'app2.views.enrich' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Which leaves me flummoxed, as `app2.views.enrich` does indeed exist. What am I to do? The path exists and operates correctly (if I visit `/app2/<aid>/add/`, I am welcomed with the proper HTTP response), but on *redirect* it doesn't actually seem to work, and neither do any of the other views.

Some context:

- There are 3 apps in this Django project
- All of these apps have proved functional along with their views
- The versioning is Django 2.1 and Python 3.7.1

*Disclaimer: the app is not actually called 'app2', that is simply a placeholder.*

Answer (score 1):

The wrong in this program is `redirect(enrich, ...)`, the redirect first argument can't be a view function or view class.

ref from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/shortcuts/#redirect:

> The arguments could be:
>
> - A model: the model's `get_absolute_url()` function will be called.
> - A view name, possibly with arguments: `urls.reverse()` will be used
>           to reverse-resolve the name.
> - A URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.

The error message of `Reverse for 'app2.views.enrich' not found`, is because it print the view function's qualified name.

You should use str `'enrich'` as first argument in `redirect()`.

Comment: You are correct, it must be a `str`, but the namespace of the app must also be specified (which i noted in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the context of multiple apps, one has to specify the app namespace in the redirect.

```
return redirect('app2:enrich', ...
```